# Fluid mechanics resources for pure mathematicians?

Tags: reference-request, fluid-dynamics

I'm currently taking a course on fluid mechanics, and I'm finding it very difficult to become motivated and interested. I've always been more interested in the pure math side of my courses, and love finding the links between pure and applied mathematics. I'm hoping to find a resource (book, blog, etc.) that would make ties between fluids and pure math.

Currently, all the resources I've found have a presentation that's tied to physics or engineering. And while I realize that is, to some extent, inevitable, I'm sure there must be some more abstract treatments of the topic out there.

I'm not necessarily looking for something I can understand, just something that can provide me with something to think about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two suggestions:

- [J.Marsden and A.Chorin, *A mathematical introduction to fluid mechanics*](http://books.google.com/books?id=0Iglq1WA5PQC&dq=Marsden%20Chorin&source=bl&ots=fh289IdNIu&sig=IW0LsJ7nmLbQU6FaiHD8zkGwDYg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=waleUOqnEoPf4QSbioHACQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA)
- [V.I. Arnold and B.A. Khesin *Topological Methods in Hydrondynamics*](http://books.google.com/books?id=9Iwrt0l0nFMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Arnold%20topological%20methods&source=bl&ots=8EboHOnalu&sig=ZlmmgB8FyfZj9P_V-0YDtSMpFiE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eqpeUK-tCoiA4gSq1YHoAQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA)

The second book definitely will provide something to think about.

Comment: Judging from the contents page alone, the second looks promising. Thanks!